# send email whenever ec2 is shut down using serverless

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

i am new to serverless framework and aws, and i need to create a lambda function on python that will send email whenever an ec2 is shut down, but i really don't know how to do it using serverless. So please if any one could help me do that or at least give me some tracks to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using serverless, you can define the event trigger for your function like this...

```
functions:
  shutdownEmailer:
    handler: shutdownEmailer.handler
    events:
      - cloudwatchEvent:
          event:
            source:
              - "aws.ec2"
            detail-type:
              - "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
            detail:
              state:
                - shutting down
          enabled: true
```

Then, you can expect your lambda to be called every time that event happens.

Comment: thanks a lot bro, it was exactly what i was looking for, an yml file to set all parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CloudWatch for this.

You can create a cloudwatch rule

1. Service Name -  Ec2
2. Event Type - EC2 Instance change notification
3. Specific state(s) - shutting-down

Then use an SNS target to deliver email.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a **CloudWatch Event**.

In short, a CloudWatch event is capable of triggering a Lambda function and passing it something like this:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "123-456-abc",
  "detail-type": "EC2 Instance State-change Notification",
  "source": "aws.ec2",
  "account": "1234567",
  "time": "2015-11-11T21:36:16Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:12312312312:instance/i-abcd4444"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "instance-id": "i-abcd4444",
    "state": "shutting-down"
  }
```

From there, you can parse this information in your Python code running on Lambda. To get Instance ID of shutting-down instance, you will use something like this:

```
instance_id = event["detail"]["instance-id"]
```

Then you can use Amazon SES (Simple Email Service) API with help from official boto3 library and send an email. See: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_email

Of course, you will also need a proper IAM role with necessary privileges to use SES attached to your Lambda function. You can make a new one easily on AWS IAM Roles page.

It might seem overwhelming at first, for starters:

- go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#rules:action=create (if link is broken: AWS Dashboard > CloudWatch > Rules)
- Create a new rule.
- Under "Event Source" select EC2 as Service Name, and "EC2 Instance State-change Notification" as Event Type.
- Click on "Specific States". You can simply select "shutting-down" here but I would also choose "stopping" and "terminated" just to make sure.
- Save it, go to Lambda, add this Event in Triggers tab and start writing your code.

Comment: thanks, it really helps i will test all that and try to do it on serverless